# Inject/access service inside a class decorator in NestJS

Tags: typescript, nestjs

how I can inject/access a service inside an custom class decorator in NestJS?

I create a class decorator (`AuditMethods`), and after originar method execution I need to call the method `someMethod` from `AuditService`. the problem is the AuditService doesn't exists in the decorator target class.

I already try inject the service, but didn't work. `auditPublisher` is always undefined.

```js
// workspace/libs/audit/src/lib/decorators/audit-methods.decorator.ts

import { Inject, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

export function AuditMethods() {
  const injectAuditPublisherService = Inject(AuditService);

  return function (target: any) {
    injectAuditPublisherService(target, 'auditPublisher');

    const auditPublisher: AuditService = target.auditPublisher;
    console.log(auditPublisher); // undefined

      const originalMethod = target.prototype['xpto'];

      target.prototype['xpto'] = async function (...args: any[]) {
        const result = await originalMethod.apply(this, args);

        auditPublisher.someMethod(result);

        return result;
      };
  };
}

// workspace/libs/audit/src/lib/audit.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class AuditService {

  public async someMethod(result) {
    console.log(result);
  }
}


// workspace/libs/audit/src/lib/audit.module.ts

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuditService } from './audit.service';

@Module({
  providers: [AuditService],
  exports: [AuditService],
})
export class AuditModule {}


-------

// workspace/libs/example/src/lib/some-class.ts

@AuditMethods()
export class SomeClass {
  async xpto(userId: number): Promise<number> {
    // code
  }
}


// workspace/libs/example/src/lib/example.module.ts

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppConfigModule } from '@workspace/config';
import { AuditModule } from '@workspace/audit';

@Module({
  imports: [
    AuditModule,
  ],
})
export class ExampleModule {}
```

Comment: Question is currently unclear as stated. Writing a decorator which causes automatic property injection is different from writing a decorator which expect such a property to be present. Explain the thinking in your code and where it fails.